# QT height issue of ScrollablePage

Tags: qt, menu, qml, drawer

I'm trying to customise the Qt Drawer menu (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-gallery-gallery-qml.html).
The main change that I've made is replacing the Pane block by the separate view ProjectList:

```
StackView {
    id:homeView
    anchors.fill: parent

    initialItem:ProjectsList{
    }
    }
}
```

ProjectList.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

ScrollablePage {
    id:projectsListPage

    ListView {
        id: listView2
        anchors.fill: parent

        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            width: parent.width
            text: model.title
        }

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { title: qsTr("2Projects list2j") }
            ListElement { title: qsTr("Projects liste") }
            ListElement { title: qsTr("Projects listr") }
            ListElement { title: qsTr("Projects list3") }
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can see only one line of the list, others are hidden, but I can scroll it. Help me, please, fill the entire page by ScrollView (height attribute isn't working :( )

ScrollablePage:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Page {
    id: page

    default property alias content: pane.contentItem

    Flickable {
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: pane.implicitHeight
        flickableDirection: Flickable.AutoFlickIfNeeded

        Pane {
            id: pane
            width: parent.width
        }

        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your ListView will try to fill parent based on `anchors.fill: parent` instruction, but `projectsListPage` has no size defined, and I am not sure that `initialItem` from `StackView` will give your `ProjectsList` instance correct dimensions.

Also, you have extra parentess in your `StackView` code, and qml file for Project**s**List element has different name: ProjectList.qml, those should be the same, if you are not using `qmldir` with definitions for paths and elements' names.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `ScrollablePage`? I think your problem lies within your *modifications*.

Comment: Dmitriy, thank you, but my aim is to fill the whole area by content of the current page, so I'm unable to set the size of elements. As for naming, yeah, it's my typo, sorry.
derM, thank you, sure, I have attached it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The `ListView` itself is a `Flickable` so it is scrollable by itself. Now you pack a `Flickable` within a `Flickable` which seems both unnecessary and problematic.

The size of the outer `Flickable` from the `ScrollablePage` is determined by the `height` of the `Pane`, and the `Pane`s height is determined by the size of the `ListView` - that is 0. So it is obvious, this can not work.
You might set the `ListView`'s height to its own `contentItem.height` which would work, but you have all elements loaded and don't profit of the dynamic creation and destruction anymore.

If I understand you right, you want to have the Page just as large as needed, but have a maximum size of the parent of the `StackView`.

I would recommend, not to use your `ScrollablePage` but a common `Page` instead, and pack the `ListView` directly in there. Let the `ListView` fill the `Page` and set the `Page.implicitHeight` to `Math.max(parent.height, listView.contentItem.height)` or something like this.

**You definately MUST SET a size for a `ListView` as it does not provide a meaningful implicitHeight!!!**

Comment: Thnx so much, it's my fault. I've just removed the ScrollablePage and it's working! I'm dumb...
I've followed to their example and thought that it's essential part of the Drawer menu and never thought that I have to remove it... I should read the Quick element's manual more careful.